# Laravel : How to hide data depend on some condition?

Tags: laravel

If I have this model :

```
$result = 
    [
     {
      "date":"1/1/2021",
      "actions":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "title:"test",
          "sub_actions":[
             {
               "id":1
             }
             {
               "id":2
             }
            ]
           }
         ],
       "date":"2/1/2021",
      "actions":[
        {
          "id":2,
          "title:"test2",
          "sub_actions":[
             {
               "id":1
             }
             {
               "id":2
             }
            ]
           }
         ]
       }
    ]
```

I want if in some of these dates the action count be zero for some reason to not display both (date and actions) in the list?
something like this :

```
if($result->actions->count() == 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the output of a query, but for the general case, if you had a json looking like

```
  [
    {
      "date": "1/1/2021",
      "actions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "test",
          "sub_actions": [
            {
              "id": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2/1/2021",
      "actions": [
        
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and you decoded into a variable like so

```
$resultArray = json_decode(
   '[{"date":"1/1/2021","actions":[{"id":1,"title":"test","sub_actions":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}]},{"date":"2/1/2021","actions":[]}]'
);
```

you could turn that to a collection and then apply `filter` on it

```
$recordsWithActions = collect($resultArray)->filter(fn($row)=> count($row->actions))->all();
```

or

```
$recordsWithActions = collect($resultArray)->filter(
    function($row) { 
      // it would be $row['actions'] if you did json_decode(...,true)
      return  count($row->actions)>0;
    }
)->all();
```

I left you the example using arrays instead of objects at [Laravel Playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/ae3a3933-6163-47ff-80d7-3746452a1a50)

#### Edit: Filtering on nested properties

Let's leave the json encoding and decoding aside for a minute. You have  an array of soccer fixtures, each of which can have zero or more matches, and each match in turn can have zero or more predects (predictions?).

You want to display only matches with more than zero *predect*s. This will prune matches without said property and if the pruned matches array is empty, then the parent fixture should be pruned from the final result as well.

The [Collecttion::filter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) method evaluates every item for the truthyness of a condition. `count($match['predect'])` is zero, and zero is a falsy value, same as `false`, `NULL`, an empty string or an empty array. A non empty array would satisfy either the truthyness test by itself, or the assertion that `count($array)` or `count($array)>0`.

Checking [your example](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/c8ee2360-ba00-4b7e-aefd-8cf6a8aad78f), you did the equivalent of (I won't use arrow functions for the sake of clarity):

```
     // show me the items for which the next condition is truthy
     $myresults = collect($fixtures)->filter(function ($fixture) {

        // matches is a collection of items for which is true that
        $matches = collect($fixture['matches'])
                ->filter(function ($match) {
                    // their predect property is not empty
                    return count($match['predect']);
                });

        // this is the truthyness test to check
        return $matches;
     })->all();
```

`$matches` is a collection, which is not falsy no matter it doesn't have items. However, if you used, instead:

```
           $matches = collect($fixture['matches'])
                ->filter(function ($match) {
                    // their predect property is not empty
                    return count($match['predect']);
                })->all();
```

and `$matches` was an empty array, it would "bubble up" effectively pruning the parent fixture. If any fixture has at least one match passing the truthyness test, then it will show up in the final result. It's `matches` key would not be filtered, since you aren't altering their contents on the basis of the nested filter.

If you want to redeclare the matches of each fixture to prune the ones without `predect`, you would use the  `Collection::map` method like so:

```
 $fixtures_with_passing_matches = collect($fixtures)
     ->map(function($fixture) {
        $fixture['matches'] =  collect($fixture['matches'])
                ->filter(function ($match) {
                    return count($match['predect']);
                })->all();
        return $fixture;
     })->all();
```

you can chain your filter method after the mapping, therefore pruning the fixtures that, after redeclaring their matches, have none left

```
 $fixtures_with_passing_matches = collect($fixtures)
     ->map(function($fixture) {
        $fixture['matches'] =  collect($fixture['matches'])
                ->filter(function ($match) {
                    return count($match['predect']);
                })->all();
        return $fixture;
     })->filter(function($fixture) { 
        return  count($fixture['matches'])>0;
     })->all();
```

So let's look at the following example array:

```
$fixtures = [
    [
        "fixture_id" => 1,
        "matches" => [
            [
                "match_id" => 1,
                "home" => "Turkey",
                "away" => "Italy",
                "predect" => [
                    [
                        "h_predect" => 1,
                        "a_predect" => 1
                    ]
                ]
            ], [
                "match_id" => 3,
                "home" => "Denmark",
                "away" => "Finland",
                "predect" => []
            ]
        ]
    ], [
        "fixture_id" => 2,
        "matches" => [
          [
            "match_id" => 4,
            "home" => "France",
            "away" => "Norway",
            "predect" => []
          ]
        ]
    ], [
        "fixture_id" => 3,
        "matches" => []
    ]
];
```

- The last fixture doesn't have `matches`, so it will be filtered out
- The second fixture has matches, but none of them has `predect`, therefore are filtered out, leaving the parent fixture without `matches`m therefore filtering it out as well
- The first fixture has matches, of which one doesn't have `predect` so it's filtered out. This leaved the parent fixture with just one match

The final array is

```
$fixtures = [
    [
        "fixture_id" => 1,
        "matches" => [
            [
                "match_id" => 1,
                "home" => "Turkey",
                "away" => "Italy",
                "predect" => [
                    [
                        "h_predect" => 1,
                        "a_predect" => 1
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

See the working example in this [Laravel Playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/6ec8a56c-9105-4a8b-8a17-84327185c5c3)

Comment: Thank you too much ,I tried on more complex json data like this :; ,my json data containe two object (date and matches) ,matches have many object one of them is predect ,I used this but not works : $results = collect($resultArray)->filter(fn ($rows) => collect($rows['matches'])->filter(fn ($row) => count($row['predect'])))->all()

Comment: look at this please : https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/c8ee2360-ba00-4b7e-aefd-8cf6a8aad78f

Comment: I edited my answer and left you another example:  https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/6ec8a56c-9105-4a8b-8a17-84327185c5c3